# Auto complete combo box in java problems

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox, autocomplete

I am using

```
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.Configurator;
Configurator.enableAutoCompletion(combo);
```

to make my combo box auto complete. But this is not working. My combo box name is combo. When i am importing NetBeans says that that import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.Configurator; does not exists. Can anyone suggest a simple way to auto complete the combo box. I cannot add more lines of codes because i have some restriction in terms of lines of codes for this project.

Comment: Did you import the library into your project?

Comment: yes i import the library but NetBeans says it does not exists. why is that so?

Comment: So you have downloaded the  .jar file and made it available in your project?

Comment: Does this library requires some .jar file?Can you help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto complete combo box in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562131/auto-complete-combo-box-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the .jar- File ( for example from here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/swinglabs/swingx/swingx-all/1.6.3/swingx-all-1.6.3.jar

You then go to File > Project Properties > Libraries > Compile-Time Libraries in your Netbeans Project
and add the .jar you just downloaded.

Comment: I am getting some errors. It says cannot find symbol

Comment: at which step in the process?