# Wrong argument to the function - AutoComplete in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I am using a JComboBox as a cell editor for one of my JTbale column.I want to implement autocomplete in my JComboBox. I used a jar file from this link [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingx162jar.htm). When I run my program it is giving me this error:

```
at Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/Configurator, method: enableAutoCompletion signature: (Ljavax/swing/JComboBox;)V) Incompatible argument to functionquotationTable.DescriptionColumnEditor.populateComboBox(DescriptionColumnEditor.java:68)
at quotationTable.DescriptionColumnEditor.<init>(DescriptionColumnEditor.java:31)
at quotationTable.Table.initComponent(Table.java:40)
at quotationTable.Table.<init>(Table.java:28)
at quotationInterface.TablePane.addTable(TablePane.java:40)
at quotationInterface.TablePane.<init>(TablePane.java:25)
at quotationInterface.QuotationTabPane.createQuotPane(QuotationTabPane.java:35)
at quotationInterface.QuotationTabPane.<init>(QuotationTabPane.java:23)
at quotationInterface.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:37)
at quotationInterface.MainWindow.lambda$main$0(MainWindow.java:90)
at quotationInterface.MainWindow$$Lambda$1/798154996.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have imported the right jar; this I confirmed when I checked with this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576217/auto-complete-combo-box-in-java-problems). My code for adding the functionality needed is:

```
 combo=new JComboBox(myList);
        Configurator.enableAutoCompletion(myComboBox); //this is the line generating the error.
```

How do we resolve this?
I was suspecting this line`JComboBox comboBox = [...];` what does it do? It my be that I am creating my combobox the wrong way.

Comment: Please show us the whole stacktrace.

Comment: That's the code.  You already had part of the stacktrace, we just need to see the rest (top?) of it.

Comment: okay fine, had missed something here...i added the top line

Comment: What are you importing?

Comment: @KevinWorkman where? I think I have imported the right jars.

Comment: I'm asking to see your import statements at the top of your class. This would be a lot easier if you just posted an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I have imported the right jar; this I confirmed when I checked with this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576217/auto-complete-combo-box-in-java-problems).*"

No it doesn't. That question still unanswered because OP couldn't solve their problem (see the comments on that post). Besides as far as I know there is no class named `Configurator` in [SwingX](https://java.net/projects/swingx) library which you are using to get the auto-complete decoration in your combo box. Even in [this list](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingx162jar.htm) (you've linked in your question) there is no such class:

[image: No org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.Configurator class]

Now, the right way to provide auto-complete decoration is using `AutoCompleteDecorator` as follows:

```
 JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
 AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox);
```

#### Note

Also note the current version is 1.6.4 not 1.6.2

Comment: i saw it here http: [link](//www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingx080jar.htm)....may because it it old, but I doubt.

Comment: That link is for SwingX **0**.8.0 ... The current version is **1**.6.4 You still have doubts is not the correct class? @Giovanrich

Comment: Yes it is the version that i was using.....Not doubts in correct class but in that I there is no such class since i saw it--let me try your code above

Comment: but you saw that such class exist?